# Creating a rake task for rspec in Jruby: no such file to load -- spec/rake/spectask

Tags: rspec, rake, jruby

JRuby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.9.2-p136)

Gems:

```
bundler (1.0.21)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
rake (0.8.7)
rspec (2.7.0)
rspec-core (2.7.1)
rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
sources (0.0.1)
```

In the rake file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'
require 'rake/clean'
require 'rake/gempackagetask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'spec/rake/spectask'
```

When I run rake I get: no such file to load -- spec/rake/spectask

All the examples I found online show the require that is raising the exception. This is not a rails project.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example is old. Use `rspec/core/rake_task` instead. https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/upgrade (See the upgrade section)